# Why Isn't time variable changing?

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, declaration

```js
function getTime() {
      const d = new Date();
      const secs = d.getSeconds();
      const mins = d.getMinutes();
      const hours = d.getHours();
      
      return {
        'hours': hours,
        'mins': mins,
        'secs': secs
      }
    }
   
    let time = getTime();

    setInterval(getTime, 1000);
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(`${time.hours}:${time.mins}:${time.secs}`);
    }, 1000);
```

The time displayed doesn't change. It just continually runs, outputting the same time instead of showing a change each second...

Comment: HA! I have changed to 'let' for the 'time,' as I guess that's changing within the scope of this script. But, const is okay because none of those values change within the scope of the function...That was one of the first things I thought of. Besides, I'm pretty sure that es6 will actually just error out if try to re-write to 'const'...not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not updating the `time` variable, but just calling `getTime` in `setInterval`.

This is how it should be:

```
setInterval(function() {
  time = getTime();
  console.log(`${time.hours}:${time.mins}:${time.secs}`);
}, 1000);
```

**Note:**

If you declare your `time` variable as constant with `cons` keyword, trying to change it will throw this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

**Demo:**

```js
function getTime() {
  const d = new Date();
  const secs = d.getSeconds();
  const mins = d.getMinutes();
  const hours = d.getHours();

  return {
    'hours': hours,
    'mins': mins,
    'secs': secs
  }
}

var time = getTime();

setInterval(function() {
  time = getTime();
    console.log(`${time.hours}:${time.mins}:${time.secs}`);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yup! That's it. As soon as I saw the first part of your answer...it only gets assigned once! :(

Comment: @VisWebsoft Yes, it needs to be assigned inside the `setInterval`callback.

Comment: Just did. IDK we have to wait 10 minutes to accept.

Answer (score 3):

`time` variable is declared only once, when script loads and stays in that state. Move it inside the interval to keep it updated.

```js
function getTime() {
  const d = new Date();
  const secs = d.getSeconds();
  const mins = d.getMinutes();
  const hours = d.getHours();

  return {
    'hours': hours,
    'mins': mins,
    'secs': secs
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  const time = getTime();
  console.log(`${time.hours}:${time.mins}:${time.secs}`);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are only setting the value of `time` once, to the value of `getTime()` at that moment.

If you want the value to change, you have to set the value again every iteration.

```
setInterval(() => {
    var time = getTime();
    console.log(`${time.hours}:${time.mins}:${time.secs}`);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Time is not changing because you are using variable which are not getting updated.
Here are two problems

> const time = getTime();//its called once  and time values are const
>   will never change again
>
> setInterval(getTime, 1000);//here function is getting executed but
>   return value is never used and never assigned to time variable which
>   is printed.

```js
function getTime() {
  const d = new Date();
  const secs = d.getSeconds();
  const mins = d.getMinutes();
  const hours = d.getHours();

  return {
    'hours': hours,
    'mins': mins,
    'secs': secs
  }
}

//const time = getTime();//its called once and time values are const will never change again

//setInterval(getTime, 1000);//here function is getting executed but return value is never used and never assigned to time variable which is printed.
setInterval(() => {
  var time=getTime();
  //getTime
  console.log(`${time.hours}:${time.mins}:${time.secs}`);
}, 1000);
```